# How to suppress logging output to stdout when using Jetty Websocket client?

Tags: java, logging, websocket, client, jetty

When using Jetty's Websocket client implementation and creating an instance of WebSocketClient, logging is being written to stdout as such:

> 2018-08-22 22:30:34.720:INFO::main: Logging initialized @26651ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog

This occurs as soon as doing this:

```
WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();
```

I tried including a jetty-logging.properties file as part of the resource bundle with log levels turned OFF but that didn't work:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StrErrLog
org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=OFF
org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.LEVEL=OFF
```

How do I suppress this?

Thanks,

Tobias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure it out by stepping into WebSocketClient() with a debugger until the message was printed to stdout.

To disable this logging announcement, set a system property.

```
System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.announce", "false");
```

I wish the [Jetty documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/configuring-logging.html) had an overview of properties it honors.

Answer (score 3):

Verified with Jetty 9.4.x: add `/jetty-logging.properties` to your classpath:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.announce=false
```

Because I'm using slf4j-simple, also `/simplelogger.properties`:

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=warn
```

Setting a system property inside the code is flaky for obvious reasons. (https://javagc.leponceau.org/2019/02/how-to-suppress-embedded-jetty-logging.html)